# How to set class or style in script tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to set class or style in script tag ?

i try to do this buy not work

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.J_countdown2').countdown({
            tmpl : '<span style='font-size: 50px; '>%{d}</span>days'
        });
    });
</script>
```

i fill `style='font-size: 50px; '`

Comment: put double quotes: `style="font-size: 50px; "`

Comment: when using like this, if you are using `single quotes` outside,then used `double quotes` inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put double quotes or escape the single ones:

```
$(function() {
    $('.J_countdown2').countdown({
        tmpl : '<span style="font-size: 50px; ">%{d}</span>days'
    });
});
```

or escape the inner single quotes with `\`:

```
tmpl : '<span style=\'font-size: 50px; \'>%{d}</span>days'
```

even you can try this too:

```
$('.J_countdown2').countdown({
    tmpl : $('<span/>', {
              class: "font50", // <----set class name
              style : "font-size:50px", // <---style if you want against class
              text : '%{d}days' //<-----put the text like this
           })
});
```

where `font50` is the class name:

```
.font50{
   font-size: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're already using jQuery, the best way is to [.addClass("className")](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) to your element and set all the styles you need in an external CSS file… :-)